# How does 0-1 knapsack have mathmatically exponential time complexty?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, knapsack-problem

I wrote an algorithm to solve 0-1 knapsack problem which works perfect which is as follows:

```
def zero_one_knapsack_problem(weight: list, items: list, values: list, total_capacity: int) -> list:
    """
    A function that implement dynamic programming to solve the zero one knapsack problem. It has exponential
     time complexity as supposed.

    :param weight: the weight list each element correspond to item at same index
    :param items: the array of items ordered same as weight list and values list
    :param values: the values list
    :param total_capacity: the total capcaity of knapsack
    :return: How to fill the knapsack
    """

    items_length = len(items)+1
    total_capacity += 1
    # Create The table
    table = [[0 for w in range(total_capacity)] for y in range(items_length)]

    for i in range(1, items_length):
        for j in range(total_capacity):
            if weight[i-1] > j:   # Item does not fit
                pass
            else:
                # calculate Take It or Not
                table[i][j] = max(values[i-1]+table[i-1][j-weight[i-1]], table[i-2][j])
    print("The optimal value to carry is: ${}".format(table[items_length-1][total_capacity-1]))
```

From the analysis the time complexity is `seta(items_length * total_capacity)` which is the summation of the 2 loops together(ignoring constants). Then i read online that this method has exponential time complexity(Not from one source many blogs says exponential also). Which I can't see how it comes for example consider any of below examples:

```
1-) 10 * 100000000000 = 1×10¹²
2-) 11 * 100000000000 = 1.1×10¹²
3-) 12 * 100000000000 = 1.2×10¹²

# difference between each
2 and 3 = 100000000000 = 1.2*10^12 - 1.1*10^12
1 and 2 = 100000000000 = 1.1*10^12 - 1*10^12
```

as you can see increasing input by 1 didn't cause any exponential growth. So how can they say this algorithm is exponential in a mathematical way.

Comment: `* total_capacity` makes your runtime [pseudopolynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), not polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a problem size of N bits, you can have, for example, sqrt(N) objects with weights about sqrt(N) bits long, and total_capacity about sqrt(N) bits long.

That makes total_capacity about sqrt(2)<sup>N</sup>, and your solution takes O(sqrt(N)*sqrt(2)<sup>N</sup>) time, which is certainly exponential.

Comment: how with ```N``` bits I can have ```sqrt(N)``` objects as you say this is incorrect with ```N``` bits i have ```2^N``` objects I suppose, so why did you you use ```sqrt(N)``` can you give a more explained answer if possible then I can see your working (any examples would be great ). Huge thanks to you.

Comment: The "problem size", which we usually denote by N in complexity statements, is the number of bits or bytes it takes to represent the problem.  For your problem, that is the number of items multiplied by the size of the weights, plus a little bit more for the total capacity and the item count.